# Issue with horizontal scroll with touchpad in gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-17.04

I have installed gnome-shell on my ubuntu 17.04 and selected Gnome at my the login screen, everything works fine, but the **horizontal scroll with touchpad doesn't work.** It works when i shift to unity but fails in gnome.

I installed **dconf-editor** and tried to enable horizontal scroll in **org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad** as mentioned in an online forum but the touchpad doesn't show up in the peripherals folder.

Any suggestions please ?